# Timeshift --clone console using

Tags: command-line, clone, timeshift

I can't run system clone via the Timeshift utility. Maybe I'm using the wrong syntax?

```
user@ubuntuserver:~$ sudo timeshift --clone
[sudo] password for user:

/dev/sdb1 is mounted at: /run/timeshift/backup, options: rw,relatime

E: Snapshot not selected
```

What`s wrong? What kind of snapshot do I need to select to create a clone in source system?

Comment: Please, specify which Ubuntu flavour and release are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Developer answered me:
"This is an old feature for cloning the current system to another disk. This feature is no longer supported and should not be used as it has many issues. Regards, Tony George On Thu, May 5, 2022, 10:39 AM – "

Answer (score 0):

I think 'partimage' might be a solution for you. Found in the repository. Synaptic is a good tool to browse the repository.